# Repeating android heads up notifications

Tags: java, android

I am able to show heads up notifications from the service. It pop up very first notification and visible to user. But thereafter if the notification is updated then it is not popping up again as first one rather it only gives notification sound and updates it, but does not pop up again as very first.

---

```
Showing very first notification from service as below : 

    public class WatchMan extends Service
    {
    NotificationManager mNotifyManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
    NotificationChannel notificationChannel;
    String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "1";

    public boolean Notif_Seven = false;
    public boolean Notif_Eight = false;
    
    public WatchMan() { }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        try
        {
            mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, null);
            mBuilder.setContentTitle("App Title")
                    .setContentText("Up and Monitoring..")
                    .setTicker("Up and Monitoring..")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_service_success)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setOnlyAlertOnce(false)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            {
                notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "My Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

                // Configure the notification channel.
                notificationChannel.setDescription("Channel description");
                notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
                notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
                notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
                notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
                notificationChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
                mNotifyManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
            }
            
            mBuilder.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
            mNotifyManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
            startForeground(1, mBuilder.build());

            
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "EXCEPTION IN SHOWING NOTIFICATION...\n");
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception is : ", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
    
        // STICKY Runnable thread WHILE ( TRUE )
        // my code goes here with multiple conditions checking
        // Say condition 7 is false and want to notify user again.
        
        if (!Notif_Seven)
        {
            Notif_Seven = true;
            mBuilder.setContentText("SET DEFAULT TYPE IN SETTINGS..");
            mBuilder.setTicker("SET DEFAULT TYPE IN SETTINGS..");
            mNotifyManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());

        }

        Thread.sleep(10000);
        continue;
        
        // Say condition 8 is false and want to notify user again.
        
        if (!Notif_Eight)
        {
            Notif_Eight = true;
            mBuilder.setContentText("SET PERCENTAGE SETTINGS..");
            mBuilder.setTicker("SET PERCENTAGE SETTINGS..");
            mNotifyManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());

        }
    }

}
```

---

It showing multiple notification tickers in 4.1 one by one, But in 5.1 onwards it shows it as heads up notifications, as it should be but only very first is popping up and rest all notifications are getting updated but not popping up. I want to let user see every notification as heads up and completely visible.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have done it with startforeground call. It is working as heads up notifications above 5.1 and in below versions it is showing ticker notifications successfully.

---

```
public class WatchMan extends Service
{
NotificationManager mNotifyManager;
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
NotificationChannel notificationChannel;
String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "1";

public boolean Notif_Seven = false;
public boolean Notif_Eight = false;

public WatchMan() { }

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    try
    {
        mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, null);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle("App Title")
                .setContentText("Up and Monitoring..")
                .setTicker("Up and Monitoring..")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_service_success)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setOngoing(true);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        {
            notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "My Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

            // Configure the notification channel.
            notificationChannel.setDescription("Channel description");
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
            notificationChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
            mNotifyManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }

        mBuilder.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        //mNotifyManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
        startForeground(1, mBuilder.build());


    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "EXCEPTION IN SHOWING NOTIFICATION...\n");
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception is : ", e);
    }
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{

    // STICKY Runnable thread WHILE ( TRUE )
    // my code goes here with multiple conditions checking
    // Say condition 7 is false and want to notify user again.

    if (!Notif_Seven)
    {
        Notif_Seven = true;
        mBuilder.setContentText("SET DEFAULT TYPE IN SETTINGS..");
        mBuilder.setTicker("SET DEFAULT TYPE IN SETTINGS..");
        mBuilder.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        startForeground(1, mBuilder.build());

    }

    Thread.sleep(10000);
    continue;

    // Say condition 8 is false and want to notify user again.

    if (!Notif_Eight)
    {
        Notif_Eight = true;
        mBuilder.setContentText("SET PERCENTAGE SETTINGS..");
        mBuilder.setTicker("SET PERCENTAGE SETTINGS..");
        mBuilder.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        startForeground(1, mBuilder.build());

    }
}

}
```